# How can I change the location of the label on Bottom Navigation Bar on the Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

Hello I have a Bottom Navigation Bar looks like this:[click here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKXtx.png)

What I am trying to do is that changing the place of the text. I mean My Icon's and My Label's should look like side-by-side. ([click here to see what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKTQx.png)
Looks like a simple thing to do but I couldnt find anything to do it. Thank you

And here is my code:

```
PageController _pageController = PageController(
initialPage: 0, ); int currentIndex = 0;
Widget childWidget = ChildWidget(
number: AvailableNumber.First, 
); @override
void dispose() {
_pageController.dispose();
super.dispose(); }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: arkaPlan,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
    selectedItemColor: bottomNavi,
    unselectedItemColor: arkaPlan,
    currentIndex: currentIndex,
    onTap: (value) {
      currentIndex = value;
      _pageController.animateToPage(
        value,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      );

      setState(() {});
    },
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(LineIcons.home),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
        label: ("Second"),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
        label: ("Third"),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
        label: ("Third"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: PageView(
    controller: _pageController,
    onPageChanged: (page) {
      setState(() {
        currentIndex = page;
      });
    },
    children: <Widget>[
      ChildWidget(number: AvailableNumber.First),
      ChildWidget(number: AvailableNumber.Second),
      ChildWidget(number: AvailableNumber.Third),
      ChildWidget(number: AvailableNumber.Third)
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom package from pub.dev **or** use `Wrap` widget for `icon` in `BottomNavigationBarItem`.

**Solution 1**

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Wrap(
    children: [
      Icon(LineIcons.home),
      Text('Home'),
    ],
  ),
  label: '',
),
```

**Solution 2**

Here are some custom packages:

- https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar
- https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_navy_bar
- https://pub.dev/packages/google_nav_bar

Comment: Hello, Using Wrap for this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Row` instead of `Icon` because `icon:` asks for a `Widget` and not an  `Icon` specifically. So try this:

```
/// label can't be null, so just set an empty string to label

items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Row(children: [
          Icon(Icons.trending_up),
          Text('Home'),
        ],),
        label: '',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Row(children: [
          Icon(Icons.trending_up),
          Text('second'),
        ],),
        label: '',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Row(children: [
          Icon(Icons.trending_up),
          Text('third'),
        ],),
        label: '',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Row(children: [
          Icon(Icons.trending_up),
          Text('test'),
        ],),
        label: '',
      ),
    ],
```